# What is an open tuple in python?

Tags: python, tuples, variable-assignment

I know the syntax `tup = ("x",)` allows Python to recognise that `tup` is a tuple rather than a string, but is there any difference between `a = (2,3,)` and `b = (2,3)`?

Such assignment yields:

```
>>> a == b
True
```

Comment: No, there's no difference

Comment: see here https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax.

Comment: Try printing `a` You will see no difference with `b`

Comment: `a = b` statement return `True` ?? or `a==b` return 'True'

Comment: There's only a difference between a tuple and a non-tuple. The visual length of the tuple is irrelevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can assign value `tuple` in following ways

```
>>> a = (2,3)
>>> b = (2,3,)
>>> c = 2,3
>>> a==b
True
>>> a==c
True
>>> b==c
True
>>> d = 2,3,
>>> a==d
True
```

Comment: Don't forget `d = 2,3,`!

Answer (score 1):

It can be used to show that a one-tuple is in fact a tuple (as you already know) eg.

```
x = (1,) # and not x = (1) which is not a tuple
```

It's good to make a habit of using the trailing `,` for whenever you update your code.

eg.

```
allowed_ext = ('gif', 'png',)
```

then if you remove one

```
allowed_ext = ('png',)
```

You can see it's still a tuple and you don't have to worry about writing

```
allowed_ext = ('png')
```

by accident.